# git: How to undo my last "git push -f" without previous versions?

Tags: git, github

I have a repo1 on github and had the latest clean version (let's call it `"latest-version"`).

I cloned it but...

I did:

```
rm -fr .git
git init
git remote add origin <repo1 url>"
```

Then, I modified various files and ran `"git push -f origin master"` to overwrite all the files.

With no previous history/log in my local .git directory, how can I remove my last push so that I can get back the `"latest-version"` files on repo1?

That is, I wish I didn't run any of the above commands and just had the original `"latest-version"` files.

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: You cannot remove .git directory and then add remote because your project is not a git repository anymore. Probably, `rm -fr .git` was run in different directory and had no effect. So it is irrelevant in this question

Comment: Hi SIREN, sorry but I just edited it to include "git init" that I had run before that.

Comment: Do you have physical access to your remote repo?

Comment: I checked each file in the github repo but couldn't find any previous versions in history. Looks like, I might have completely overwritten all the previous commits with my push. As I still do have the original clone in a separate directory that I didn't modify at all, I just ran "git push -f origin master" and it put the "latest-version". I admit that I made the stupid mistake but what could have been the best way to revert and remove my bad commit, if I didn't have the pristine copy of the clone?

Comment: GitHub *may* have a backup of their copy of the repository from before the push. But they might not. In general, the more you pay them, the more they store on their side to save your butt if you screw up. :-)  So if you have a free account, well, good luck; if you have a paid one, talk to someone there. Even with the free account you *may* be able to recover since, for efficiency, they don't scrub stuff often. But you'll need to find commit hash IDs.

Answer (score 4):

You can try GitHub's reflog.

Taken from:

- https://objectpartners.com/2014/02/11/recovering-a-commit-from-githubs-reflog/
- https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f.

First, use GitHub’s Events API to retrieve the commit SHA:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/events
```

This will return a JSON response which you can read through to find the last commit from the lost branch. Use the commit message and approximate times to narrow your search.

Next, use GitHub’s Refs API to create a new branch pointing to that commit:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"ref": "refs/heads/your-new-branch", "sha": "384f275933d5b762cdb27175aeff1263a8a7b7f7"}' https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/git/refs
```

The "ref" in the JSON above is Git ref we want to create, it **must** be of the form `refs/heads/your-new-branch`, where *your-new-branch* is the name of the branch we want to create in Git.
The "sha" is the commit that we want this new branch to point to.

Now if you pull up your repository in GitHub, you will see the new branch and doing a `git fetch` will retrieve that new branch to your local repository.

Probably you will need to authenticate. Here is the authentication documentation https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#authentication